# SyncAdapter uses only the latest extras for multiple requestSync() calls

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I'm using a `SyncAdapter` and GCM to notify my app of different types of changes on the backend server. For example, if change A happens on the server, I do a push notification with a field called change_a that I pass to the `SyncAdapter` through `ContentResolver.requestSync()`. This way, the `SyncAdapter` knows what to sync from the server. Similarly, for a change B, I send a field called change_b.

This works perfectly except for one use case. I send a change_a notification, it calls `ContentResolver.requestSync()` but, because there is no network availability, the `SyncAdapter` is not yet called. If after that, I send a change_b notification, again `ContentResolver.requestSync()` is called with the new field. And then, when the networks is up, the `SyncAdapter` is called but only with the latest field change_b and accordingly, it won't sync the change A.

So, basically, `ContentResolver.requestSync()` overrides all previous `requestSync()` calls that haven't yet triggered the SyncAdapter. The SyncAdapter runs with the latest extras that were sent.

One solution to this is to not differentiate between a change A and a change B and have the `SyncAdapter` sync everything. But this is costly for the bandwidth. I want to control what and when to sync. Is there something I could do to fix this (a syncadapter flag maybe)?

Comment: Store the field (_a, _b etc.) in shared preferences / sqlite when your sync adapter triggers, remove upon successful sync - when a failed attempt to sync _a is discovered when triggered for _b the problem should be solved.

Comment: Yes. I was thinking about this solution. But I was hoping for something useful in the API. If there is no other way, I'll go with this one.

Comment: Well, you could always just subclass your sync adapter and register one for syncing _a & one for _b, thus a new request-sync for _b won't mess with the retries for _a.

Comment: Do you use different collapse keys for changes a and b?

Comment: @NickT No. But I will definitely use from now on. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I drew the wrong conclusions. Actually, after some further testing, if `requestSync()` is called with different extras, `SyncAdapter` is called several times, for each different Bundle.

My problem was somewhere else. When I would receive a push notification, I would schedule an alarm to trigger the sync request and I would use a `PendingIntent` with the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`, which meant that if another push notification came before the alarm went off, the alarm would be overwritten with the new data. And so, if the device was offline, when it came online, it received all the pending push notifications and there would be only one alarm set with the data from the most recent push notification.

The way I solved this problem, is by setting a different action on each PendingIntent so that setting a new alarm of the same type doesn't overwrite the other types of alarms.

And a improvement to this would be to add a collapse_key for each type of sync so that only one of each kind of push notification gets delivered to the device.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems I drew the wrong conclusions. Actually, after some further testing, if requestSync() is called with different extras, SyncAdapter is called several times, for each different Bundle.

If you use different extras in multiple calls to `requestSync()`, then `performSync()` will be called for each `requestSync()`. I want to add proof: the `toKey()` call inside [SyncOperation.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/core/java/android/content/SyncOperation.java) incorporates values from inside the extras Bundle. This prevents `SyncManager` from deduping these `SyncOperations`.